# iOS Cordova Crash: Application tried to present modally an active controller UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have been stuck on troubleshooting this for several weeks now and have no idea on what is causing the crash.

**USERS REPORTING:** A few of my users are reporting that the App crashes as soon as it is launched. Even before the login screen appears.

**CRASH REPORT:** I see a lot of crash reports in my App Centre that has the message: `SIGABRT: Application tried to present modally an active controller <UIViewController: 0x10550a9b0>.`

**DEVICES and USERS:** It appears this crash only happens to about 10% of my users. All of them are iOS users only. Android users don't have this issue.

**Steps tried:**

Honestly, I dont know where to start. I dont understand where to start looking and what could be causing the issue. I suspect the issue is from one of the plugins, but which plugin is it? Also none of the plugin authors I have followed up so far have responded to my queries. The more frustrating part is, I could not replicate this issue at all. I tried almost all of the reported devices and their iOS in my Simulators, but it all worked fine for me. I also tried it from my iPhone 8 and it worked fine. Although some users continue to report that it keeps on crashing, have no idea how to troubleshoot this and which plugin is causing the issue.

Can someone help me on what I can try and look into next please? Any suggestion is helpful. Do you suspect any of the plugins I have in my App that can cause this issue? My App developed in ionic cordova (ionic v1). I know the Angular part of the codes but have no idea on Objective C.

Below are the screenshots of the crash report I got from App Centre which doesn't seem to point out much on where the source is.

**App Centre Crash Reports:**

[image]

**Devices:**

[image]

**ionic cordova plugins list:**

```
> cordova plugin ls
code-push 3.0.1 "CodePushAcquisition"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.2 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-appcenter-analytics 0.5.1 "App Center Analytics for Cordova"
cordova-plugin-appcenter-crashes 0.5.1 "App Center Crashes for Cordova"
cordova-plugin-appcenter-shared 0.5.1 "App Center shared code for Cordova"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-code-push 1.12.0 "CodePush"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.2.1 "File Opener2"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-headercolor 1.0 "HeaderColor"
cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation 0.0.1 "cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions 1.2.0 "iOS Permissions"
cordova-plugin-mediapicker-dmcsdk 2.4.7 "MediaPicker"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.4-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
ionic-plugin-deeplinks 1.0.15 "Ionic Deeplink Plugin"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.7.0 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

**ionic info:**

> cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0 ios 5.0.1
> Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.3
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
> ios-sim    : 8.0.2 
> Node       : v11.12.0
> npm        : 5.7.1 
> OS         : macOS
> Xcode      : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504
> ```
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME : not set
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was due to one of the plugins (MediaPicker) used in my ionic cordova app. It was one of the recent commit on that plugin that was causing this crash error in some iOS. I reverted this plugin back to an order version which seems to resolve the error. I have reported this to the author of that plugin so he can look into it.